# Why is this function call returning undefined as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing

I have written a simple JavaScript code to print the max number of an array and get undefined printed as well.

```
let arrNums = [1,2,5,19,20];
const maxNum = function(arr) {
if (arr.length != 0) {
    console.log(Math.max(...arr));
}
else{
    console.log("Empty");  
}}

console.log(maxNum(arrNums));
```

Comment: because it doesn't return anything and you are console.log the return value (if you don't return anything from a function the return value is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything. Return the `Math.max()` and the `'Empty'` for it to work. After that you can just use `console.log(maxNum(arrNums));` outside the function. See below for an example of this:

```js
const arrNums = [1, 2, 5, 19, 20];
const maxNum = function (arr) {
    if (arr.length != 0) {
        return Math.max(...arr);
    } else {
        return 'Empty';
    }
}

console.log(maxNum(arrNums));
```

**Hoped this helped!**